# Two Web Apps. Two root site collections on them. HOW?

Tags: powershell, site-collection, web-application, managed-path

I've spend half a day.

I have web application http://one on port 80 and site collection on it.
I create second web application with separated site, http://two on port 80(url is added in A-records). Want to create root site collection on http://two.

Cannot create site collection in GUI(it adds "**/sites/**" managed path, which I don't want to).

Cannot create via powershell, tried like this

```
New-SPSite http://two -OwnerAlias "domain\sp_admin"-Name "Home" -Template 
STS#0
```

or like this

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication http://two;
New-SPSite http://two -OwnerAlias "domain\sp_admin" -HostHeaderWebApplication $w -Name "Home" -Template STS#0
```

..it says

> New-SPSite : The URL 'http://bussy' is in use as an alternate access
>   URL or as the URL of a host header site.  Please choose a different 
>   URL and try again.

..I cannot delete address from AAM's becouse of

> remove-SPAlternateURL : You cannot delete the default zone alternate
>   URL.

It does not want to remove from default zone becouse of error "something went wrong" and deletes from there only with deleting whole webApp..

I looked in Central Admin in Appl-on Management-> Managed Path. There are "(root)" and "sites" checkboxes, but I don't understand what they really do( It does not change something if I add "(root)"..

and so on)

**upd.:** my problem was in the other plane - LoopbackCheck.

I created WebApps and site collections in powershell, script gave me some errors and because of turned on LoopbackCheck - I wasn't able to log in to site collection. It pointed me in a wrong way and I decided that there was error and site collection does not exists. But it was created and existed :) so GUI proposed me only "/sites/" option).

Option to turn Loopback check off in powershell:

```
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa -Name "DisableLoopbackCheck" -value "1" -PropertyType dword
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have both web application properly configured. Make sure both DNS are properly registered.

- Create Web Applications on http://one port 80 and http://secondwebapp
  port 80.
- once 1st web app created it will ask to create the root level site collection. I think, this is where you created 1st root level.
- Now once 2nd web app created same message will appear and ask for create the root site collection. When you click on the link, on next page...Make sure you select the newly created web app, check from top drop down.

if still issue, could you please share the screen print.

Comment: Hi! Yes You are right, it should be created. I had a problem with loopbackcheck, updated an answer.